# BCP Export Automatically Converts Empty Strings to NUL

Tags: c#, encoding, bcp, xp-cmdshell

All, in this post [xp_cmdshell Query Length Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10995117/626442) I managed to obtain a fix for a problem I was having with the query size limit using xp_cmdshell. The reason I was writing such a long query was to attempt to get around another problem, the fact that bcp seems to convert empty strings (from a table containing fields with empty strings) into some encoded character ('NUL' or 'r', or something). This is effecting what I can use my exported data for. The export query I have is

```
string strBcp = String.Format(
    "declare @sql varchar(8000) " +
    "select @sql = 'bcp \"SELECT * FROM [{0}]..[ivwTmpDrgDataView];\" ' +" +
    "'queryout \"{1}\\DRGData.txt\" -c -t -T -S ' + @@servername " +
    "exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql;",
    strDatabase,
    strDataDir);
```

This works fine, but in the exported file database values are converted

```
NULL -> Empty String (Which is fine!)
Empty String -> Some strange character
```

I could read the .txt file with C# and then recode - **what is the best way to convert my 'strange character' back to what it should be, an empty string?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, if `bcp` converted both null and empty strings to the same output (let's say an empty string), then there would be no way to disambiguate them later.

Comment: So what is the best way to convert my strange character to empty string. That is to get bcp to write an empty string as an empty string?

Comment: by using `coalesce` or `IsNull` in your output query?

Answer (score 1):

BCP converts NULL to empty string so use NULL instead of empty string.

[More Description](http://aartemiou.blogspot.com.au/2015/03/handling-null-character-x00-when.html)

[bcp utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)